# Where is the redirect_url specified in the google api console? It isn't listed and there is no option to add it

Tags: google-api

I require a redirect_url to get a refreshToken for a service account so it can access the api.

There is no redirect_url specified in the api console, there is no option to add one, at all, anywhere.

How do I find out what the redirect_url is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto your google console with the following url https://code.google.com/apis/console/

and click API access there you can create a Client ID with your Application details with Redirect url